# Having trouble while encoding json Array in php

Tags: php, json

I have two different queries which I have to append in same array in form of JSON..

Here is my code from 1st query...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result,array('name'=>$row[0],'photo'=>$row[1],'rollno'=>$row[2],'id'=>$row[3]));
}
```

Here is my second query push similar as first one.. number of rows is always same as above query

```
array_push($result,array('status'=>'$status');
```

After that I'm encoding them like this

```
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Here is what I am getting

```
{"result":[{"name":"Abhishek Singh","photo":"http:\/\/onsitesupport.info\/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png","rollno":"1","id":"26"},
          {"status":"status"}]
```

But I want to result like this

```
 {"result":[{"name":"Abhishek Singh","photo":"http:\/\/onsitesupport.info\/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png","rollno":"1","id":"26","status":"status"}]
```

I mean status will merge into my every node... how can I achieve this..?

Comment: user array_merge insted of array_push  like this array_merge($result,array('status'=>'$status');

Comment: @JYoThI not worked after doing this it was added like this.... `{"result":{"0":{"name":"Abhishek Singh","photo":"http:\/\/onsitesupport.info\/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png","rollno":"1","id":"26"},"status":"status"}}`

Comment: try my updated comment

Comment: @JYoThI status gone right now... `{"result":[{"name":"Abhishek Singh","photo":"http:\/\/onsitesupport.info\/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png","rollno":"1","id":"26"}]}`

Comment: do a `$result['status'] = $status;` then do your `array_push`

Comment: same as my comment just status added before

Comment: why not this array_push($result,array('name'=>$row[0],'photo'=>$row[1],'rollno'=>$row[2],'id'=>$row[3],'status'=>$status));

Comment: Can you give an example result if your first query has multiple rows? I.e., do you have a status for each record?

Comment: @S.Imp got my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below to add status field to each array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('name'=>$row[0],'photo'=>$row[1],'rollno'=>$row[2],'id'=>$row[3]));
}

$res_row = 0;
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
   $status = $row2[0]; // status value here
   $result[$res_row]['status']=$status;
   $res_row++;
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Comment: a littile bit issue with it ... a status null is adding at start... all nodes are assigned a name like 0,1,2

Comment: I am not clear with your issue. can you please explain more... @Abhishek

Comment: i am getting this... {"result":{"status":null,"0":{"name":"Abhishek Singh","photo":"http:\/\/onsitesupport.info\/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png","rollno":"1","id":"26","status":"P"}}}

Comment: all status are correct but a status was adding at start

Comment: sorry it was my mistake of adding a null status.. thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Try this please, using temporary arrays that are merged after all your queries are complete:

```
// Query 1
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$tmpResults[] = $row;
}

// Query 2
$tmpResult2 = array('status'=>'$status');

// Merge Everything
$final = array_merge($tmpResults, $tmpResult2);

// Encode
$json = json_encode($final, TRUE);
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for you help